# Zoom factor of offline maps on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, offline-map

Latest Google Maps allow to download some areas as offline, so it's possible to use navigation. The trick is that the area you can choose is quite small (hopefully it's just the default).

In my case it would be Berlin. I don't care about the required space because I have quite a lot of free space on my SD card.

So the question is if it's possible to download the maps for entire city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Type *Berlin* and it shows up on map. Slide the bottom panel upwards and it shows option of downloading

[image]
[image]

2. If that doesn't cover your area of interest, choose a location beyond where you would like to go (in the example below I chose a spot nearly 400Km away) and Google Maps  throws up an option asking if you want to download (doesn't ask if the distance is very long YMMV)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible (why don't you just try it?). It was even possible before the latest update. Go to Menu - > Offline areas - > "Plus" button.
Map of Berlin takes about 300 megabytes.

Comment: I tried this way but rectangular was quite small and covered one district at most. Anyway beeshyams' solution helped. However thank you for the answer.

Comment: You can change the square size zooming in or out.